# Pandas cutting off data at index 1995

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a script that reads a bunch of csv's in a folder, renames a column, and adds the renamed columns to a master data frame using pandas.  But, I'm having an issue that pandas is cutting everything off at index 1995 even though several of my individual dataframes have over 2000 rows, has anyone else seen this?

```
    col_names = []
    col_lists = []
    newer_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in os.listdir("/Users/folder"):
       if i.endswith(".txt"):
            new_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/folder/" + i)
            print i + "   " + str(len(new_df))
            newer_df["XSample"+i]=new_df["XSample"]
            newer_df["YSample"+i]=new_df["YSample"]
    newer_df.to_csv("/Users/folder/master.csv")
```

however, despite many of my inpute being longer than 1995 rows, my master sheet is cut off at 1995

Comment: `df.iloc[:1995]` would do

Answer (score 0):

The first spreadsheet I sent into the for loop had a length of 1995 and every spreadsheet afterwards was cut down to that, I fixed this by creating a new column of just numbers from 1 to 3000 before the for loop so 3000 was the new index cutoff